React + Tailwind Design Issue: Dynamic Arrow Alignment Outside Buttons


I'm working on a React project using Tailwind CSS. My buttons feature arrows (<-) positioned outside, aligned towards the center of the button's right border with some space between them. Currently:
Buttons with shorter text display arrows correctly.
Longer text causes arrows to misalign, disrupting the design.
Design Flow:
Arrows (<-) are positioned outside each button.
They should align dynamically to the center of the right border of the button, maintaining a consistent visual distance.
Challenge: How can I adjust arrow alignment dynamically in React with Tailwind CSS, ensuring they stay centered along the right edge of buttons regardless of text length? I need to preserve the space between buttons and arrows as part of the design.
Here’s the relevant code for button component and arrow alignment:
import DiscoveryButton from '../DiscoveryButton/DiscoveryButton';

const RightSection = ({ responses, activeResponse, handleButtonClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-[80%_20%] relative">
    {/* Button Grid */}
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 items-start  space-y-4">
      {responses.map((response, index) => (
        <DiscoveryButton
          key={index}
          index={index}
          active={activeResponse === index}
          onClick={handleButtonClick}
        />
      ))}
    </div>

    {/* Navigation Arrows */}
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mt-2 pl-2  justify-center relative">
      {responses.map((response, index) => (
        // VERTICAL LINE HERE
        <div
          key={index}
          className="relative w-full pt-[--pt] bg-[image:linear-gradient(#000,#000),linear-gradient(#000,#000)] bg-[position:0_calc((theme(fontSize.base.1.lineHeight)*.5)-1px+var(--pt)),100%_var(--y,0%)] bg-[length:100%_2px,2px_var(--h,100%)] bg-no-repeat [--pt:theme(padding.4)] first:[--pt:0%] first:[--y:calc(theme(fontSize.base.1.lineHeight)*.5)] last:[--h:calc((theme(fontSize.base.1.lineHeight)*.5)+var(--pt))]"
        >
          {/* Poistioning of Arrow head */}
          <svg
            className="translate-y-[calc((theme(fontSize.base.1.lineHeight)-24px)*.75)]"
            width="16.8"
            height="24"
            viewBox="0 0 16.8 24"
            fill="none"
          >
            {/* ARROW HEAD HERE */}
            <path
              d="M0 12l12 12 1.4-1.4L4.2 12 13.4 3.4 10 0l-12 12z"
              fill="currentColor"
            />
          </svg>
          {index === 2 && (
            <div class="absolute left-full top-[--pt] h-[2px] bg-black w-5 mt-[11px]" />
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RightSection;


Any CSS or JavaScript techniques that help achieve this dynamic alignment while respecting the design's space requirement would be greatly appreciated.

Think about them like in a grid, you have to render the content that arrows aim and the arrow head in the same flex container, then it will be easier to arrange.
In case this is more complex you can use react-flow for this
